# How to build application using GMap.Net in C# with offline data?

Tags: c#, openstreetmap, offline-caching, gmap.net

I have an experiment to build offline application using GMap.Net in C#. I have a problem about provider local cache have limit max 32 MB in hard disk and 22 MB in memory. What can I to do to change it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: maybe this thread can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711953/gmap-net-offline