# Build application using GMap.Net in C# with offline maps

Tags: c#, bing-maps, ggmap, gmap.net

I'm trying to download a MapProvider to use offline map but i dont know how to download.
it works when i use ServerOnly.
This is my code:

```
GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
        _map = new GMapControl();
        Map.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.BingHybridMapProvider.Instance;
        Map.DragButton = MouseButton.Left;
        Map.MinZoom = 2;
        Map.MaxZoom = 18;
        Map.Zoom = 5;
        Map.CanDragMap = true;
        Map.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(48.8589507, 2.2775175);
        Map.ShowCenter = false;
```

Thank you everyone

Comment: You may want to check the license terms for bing maps. Building an offline database of Bing maps tiles is not permitted in the terms of use.

Comment: Yea you right. I decided to use OpenStreetMap instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the map in the local storage using the `ServerAndCache` found in `GMap.NET.AccessMode`

The following function will do the work:

```
private void gMapStoreOffline(int lat, int lng)
{

 gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.BingMapProvider.Instance;
 GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
 GMap.NET.MapProviders.OpenStreetMapProvider.UserAgent = "IE";
 
 gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.OpenStreetMapProvider.Instance;
 GMaps.Instance.OptimizeMapDb(null);

 // Define the location to cache the file
 gMapControl1.CacheLocation = @"C:\Users\<username>\..";
 gMapControl1.Zoom = 14;
 gMapControl1.Size = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
 gMapControl1.ShowCenter = false;
 gMapControl1.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(lat, lng)

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but when i use CacheOnly it show me only the areas that i already saw on ServerAndCache mode.  There is option to save the whole map to the cache ?

Comment: @AviC does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43474499/14291243) answers your question?